# Type inference with interfaces and generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I'm building a generic query dispatcher. The idea is as follows:

- A generic interface `IQuery<T>` that represents a query object
- A concrete query class has some getters and setters (implementing `IQuery<T>`)
- A generic interface `IQueryHandler<TReturnType, TQuery>` with a single method that receives a TQuery (with a constraint on `TQuery: IQuery<TReturnType>`) and returns a `TReturnType`
- Concrete handlers implementing `IQueryHandler` that receive a concrete `ConcreteQuery` and return a TQuery
- A `QueryDispatcher` that has a single method that receives a Query and returns a result. The concrete class will look up the correct handler from a DI container.

The problem is that I don't get type inference when I call the `Fetch` method on the `QueryDispatcher`. Is there anything I can do to get type inference or is this just a limitation of c#?

In theory it should know what the type arguments are since it receives a parameter of `TQuery` which has a constraint on being an `IQuery<TReturnType`.

This is the code:

```
class ConcreteClass    // This is the class of which I want to query objects
{
}
```

Query interface + concrete query class

```
interface IQuery<T>
{
}

public class ConcreteQuery : IQuery<ConcreteClass>
{
}
```

QueryHandler interface + concrete Query handler

```
interface IQueryHandler<TReturnType, TQuery> where TQuery : IQuery<TReturnType>
{
    TReturnType Fetch(TQuery query);
}

class ConcreteQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<ConcreteClass, ConcreteQuery>
{
    ConcreteClass Fetch(ConcreteQuery query)
    {
    }
}
```

QueryDispatcher (uses a DI container to resolve the correct handler)

```
class QueryDispatcher
{
    TReturnType Fetch<TReturnType, TQuery>(TQuery query) 
        where TQuery : IQuery<TReturnType>
    {
        return myDIcontainer.Get<IQueryHandler<T, TQuery>>().Fetch(query);
    }
}
```

Now when I use the QueryDispatcher like this I get an error:

```
var queryDispatcher = new QueryDispatcher();
var c = queryDispatcher.Fetch(new ConcreteQuery());
```

When I provide the type arguments everything works correctly:

```
var c = queryDispatcher.Fetch<ConcreteClass, ConcreteQuery>(new ConcreteQuery());
```

Comment: dont think that you have other option as it cannot now how to resolve TReturnType

Comment: The question is "Why not?" Is that a limitation of c#?

Comment: @Kenneth if you change the `var` to the real type, it helps?

Comment: No, tried that as well, although that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a two level type inference and the compiler won't do it.

You might want to rethink your query dispatcher. Think of it as something that takes an `IQuery<TReturnType>` and returns a `TReturnType`.

Try changing your query dispatcher to:

```
class QueryDispatcher
{
    public TReturnType Fetch<TReturnType>(IQuery<TReturnType> query) 
    {
        return myDIcontainer
            .Get<IQueryHandler<TReturnType, IQuery<TReturnType>>>()
            .Fetch(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm right that in theory, the compiler should be able to do it, but that the C#-compiler just isn't smart enough, right? The problem with changing the query dispatcher like that is that I then can't resolve different query handlers for different IQuery's