# Generic type parameter inference from constraint

Tags: c#, generics

I want to define a generic base class for entities within a system that exposes the type of the entity's identifier (e.g. int, Guid, etc.)

```
class Entity<TId>
{
}

class Product : Entity<int>
{
}
```

I can then define a generic repository interface to retrieve a dictionary of entities keyed by id.

```
interface IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : Entity<TId>
{
    Dictionary<TId, TEntity> Get();
}
```

In order to use this generic interface, I must provide both type arguments:

```
IRepository<Product, int> productRepository;
```

However, this feels redundant. Is it not possible to infer the second type argument given the type constraint in the interface definition? I want to be able to write:

```
IRepository<Product> productRepository;
```

---

Edit: I'm bad at search, apparently. As always, I couldn't find a good explanation until *after* posting.

This question was marked as duplicate but I've found what I think are better resources than the linked duplicate.

The most complete explanation is Eric Lippert's blog post:

- [Constraints are not part of the signature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/)

More relevant SO questions:

- [Working around lack of partial generic type inference with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479623/working-around-lack-of-partial-generic-type-inference-with-constraints)
- [Type inference with interfaces and generic constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958086/type-inference-with-interfaces-and-generic-constraints/40996598#40996598)

See also:

- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15166

Comment: Short answer: no, it's not possible.

Comment: No - partial parameter inference is not possible - you either specify them all or none.

Comment: You can only infer types on methods, when dealing with class generics you have to list them.

Comment: Outside the question you've asked, the problem can be solved changing the structure a little bit.
 
 `class Entity
 {
  public Type TypeProp { get; set;}
  
  public Entity(Type type)
  {
   TypeProp = type;
  }
 }

    class Entity<TId> : Entity
 {
        Entity() : base(typeof(TId))
        { }
 }

    class Product : Entity<int>
 {

 }

    interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
 {
  IDictionary Get();
 }`